# Can't get CryptosJS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I am trying to use the CryptoJS API in my express project, so I am trying to call the CryptoJS API on the clientside because I will be encrypting the users input

This is how I am calling all the files I need, the issue I am having right now is this:
[image]

To me it seems I am not sending the file to the server the right way, and that is where I am confused because I keep doing the app.get and try to get the file from the directory I specified. But it keeps not finding the directory which has confused me because I know that directory exists.

CODE

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    users = {};


server.listen(3000);


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/js"));

app.use("/style", express.static(__dirname + "/style"));

app.get("/js/bower_components/crypto-js", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/crypto-js.js');

});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('new user', function (data, callback) {
        if (data in users) {
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true);
            socket.nickname = data;
            users[socket.nickname] = socket
            updateNames();
        }

    });

    function updateNames() {
        io.sockets.emit('usernames', Object.keys(users));
    }

    socket.on('send message', function (data, callback) {
        var msg = data.trim();
        if (msg.substr(0, 3) === '/w ') {
            msg = msg.substr(3);
            var ind = msg.indexOf(' ');
            if (ind !== -1) {
                var name = msg.substr(0, ind);
                var msg = msg.substr(ind + 1);
                if (name in users) {
                    users[name].emit('whisper', {
                        msg: msg,
                        nick: socket.nickname
                    });
                    console.log('hi');
                } else {
                    callback('Error! Enter a valid user!');
                }
            } else {
                callback("Error! Enter a pm");
            }
        } else {
            io.sockets.emit('new message', {
                msg: msg,
                nick: socket.nickname
            });
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
        if (!socket.nickname) return;
        delete users[socket.nickname];
        updateNames();

    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Chatty</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="nickWrap">
        <form id="setNick">
            <p>Enter A Username:</p>
            <p id="nickError"></p>
            <input size="35" id="nickname">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="contentWrap">
        <div id="chatWrap">
            <div id='chat'></div>
            <form id='send-message'>
                <input size="35" id="message">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="users"></div>


</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script src="js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'crypto-js': 'js/bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js'
        }
    });

    require(["crypto-js"], function (CryptoJS) {
        console.log(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("Message", "Key"));
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $nickForm = $('#setNick');
            var $nickError = $('#nickError');
            var $nickBox = $('#nickname');
            var $users = $('#users');
            var $messageForm = $('#send-message');
            var $messageBox = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');

            $nickForm.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('new user', $nickBox.val(), function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('#nickWrap').hide();
                        $('#contentWrap').show();

                    } else {
                        $nickError.html('Name is taken! Choose a New one!');
                    }

                });

                $nickBox.val('');

            });


            socket.on('usernames', function (data) {
                var html = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += data[i] + '<br/>'

                }

                $users.html(html);
            });

            $messageForm.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $messageBox.val(), function (data) {
                    $chat.append('<span class = "error"' + data + "</span><br/>");

                });
                $messageBox.val('');

            });

            socket.on('new message', function (data) {
                $chat.append('<span class= "msg"<b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg +
                    "<span/><br/>");

            });

            socket.on('whisper', function (data) {
                $chat.append('<span class = "whisper"<b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg +
                    "</span><br/>");

            });
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**New Error**
[image]

**Directory Structure**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the below line in your code to make your application to refer your `JS` folder/

So, you need to replace your current,

```
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/js"));
```

as,

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "js")));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, so I have tried what you have suggested, I am still getting the same error, except this time I am getting two 404 errors

Comment: Can you please add a screen shot of that error in console?

Comment: Can you tell me where is your `require.js` residing?

Comment: It is in the `js` folder as well

Comment: One last favour...  Can you please add a screenshot of your directory structure as well??

Comment: Please discard my earlier code change suggestions and get back to your old code... Then try changing `app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/js"));` statement TO `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));`